# Возможно ли подключить к распбери пи устройтва контроля, при неработающих usb потрах?

Tags: raspberry-pi, электроника

У меня возникла проблема с распбери пи. Я делал свой проект, все работало нормально, но после одного из включений usb порты, через которые осуществлялась связь с ардуино, клавитурой и мышкой перестали работать. При том что скачков напряжения не было, малинка питалась стабильно от 5в и 2.1 ампер. HDMI работает и я могу подключиться к монитору, но с неработающими usb не могу ничего на ней сделать, есть ли возможность подключить внешние девайсы(как лкавиатура и мышь) через блютуз(если, конечно, в наличии есть девайсы поддерживающие подключение по блютуз) или через другие интерфейсы не имея доступка к usb портам. Или подскажите как исправить данную проблему, могли ли они сгореть или закоротить, при условии что внешних проявлений и предпосылок к этому не было.

Я нашел информацию, что проблема может быть в по, но я не понимаю как это возможно, если между включением где все работало, и включением где все перестало работать прошло менее 10 минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что у Вас сгорели порты. Это могло произойти из-за попадания нештатного напряжения с внешней схемы в момент ее включения или в процессе работы. Купите новую "малинку" и помните, что usb гальванически не развязан от внешнего мира. Попробуйте поискать гальваническую развязку для usb, думаю что кто-нибудь такие делает.

Ну вот, я погуглил. Действительно, есть такие гальванические развязки для usb. Вот ссылка:

https://mysku.ru/blog/aliexpress/72716.html

Там еще много ссылок, просто это первая в гугле.